# (jupyter notebook ipython debugger) How to temporarily switch set_trace() off?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, ipython

In my jupyter notebook I'm using IPython debugger. I have `set_trace()` in a function `foo()` defined in a `cell[1]`, that is called in another `cell[2]`. `foo()` is a recursive function, so it can be executed many times. `Cell[2]` is running. After checking that `some_variable` in `foo()` is behaving as expected for few times I'd like to temporarily switch off that particular `set_trace()` to keep executing `foo()` without further disturbance, but also without stopping and re-running `cell[2]`. Is there a way to do that?